# Trying to make a solid shape out of this, but can't figure out how! (Adobe Illustrator 27.7)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to figure out how to make the red lines (selection, not drawn) into a single form. Does anybody have any idea how to do that in Adobe Illustrator? Because right now, as the tree said to the lumberjack, I'm stumped.

[image: trying to figure this one out]

Comment: vector art is not like drawing. Its more like cutting with scissors so tryin to make that fill works just as well as expecting that path to cut one thing on paper. You need to rebuild this to only include the outermost lines. Should be quite easy with shapebuilder.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do here, but if you want a solid custom shape, then use the Pen Tool to make a closed path, then apply a fill to it. [see example here](https://imgur.com/a/0y7G9a1)

Comment: What's the "shape" supposed to be??? It looks just like a random scribble. Just add a fill color... or... click the `Unite` button on the Pathfinder Panel.. then adjust the fill color.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select it - Expand appearance (in object menu)
2. if you want just the outside line - you can release the compound path (Alt-sht-ctr-8) and use the first button in the pathfinder to have just the outside stroke